# Get request url in server.js file. Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have server.js file where i define my server and all settings.

And i need to define request url before declaring those settings. Because i need to define them depend on request url.

An example:

```
var siteDir = ((app.route).lastIndexOf('/admin', 0) === 0) ? '/admin' : '/client';

app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
app.set('views', __dirname + ('/template' + siteDir));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

So, if request url begins with 'admin' i will load templates from admin folder, otherwise from client.

My current implementation doesn't work, because app.route always returns '/'.

What can i do here. Please give me some advises. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the views directory per request with Express, which is what you're trying to do.

But you can use subdirectories in your calls to `res.render()`:

```
app.get('/admin/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('admin/index');   // renders '__dirname + /template/admin/index.ejs'
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('client/index');  // renders '__dirname + /template/client/index.ejs'
});
```

Comment: I know i can use this, but i wanted to find better approach. In my case i need to change settings not only for templating, but for routes, public. So your suggestion doesn't work for me. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @user2960708 perhaps re-think your app setup so you don't have to do these kinds of things?

Comment: If you know how to do it, tell me)

Comment: @user2960708 I guess you should post what exactly the problem is that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score -1):

you can write your own middleware for this.

Something like this:

```
var siteDir = "/client"; //default case;
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if(req.path == '/admin') siteDir = '/admin';
    else siteDir = '/client';
    next();
});
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
app.set('views', __dirname + ('/template' + siteDir));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: opps! I totally took it in a wrong direction. your answer is correct.